# Why does "public" give me an unresolved compilation problem?

Tags: java

I just started working with visual studio code and I'm writing my first basic program.
When I type

```
public class Variable { 
    public static void main (String[] args){
        int i;
        i = 5;
        System.out.print("The value of the variable is ");
        System.out.print(i);
    }
}
```

it tells me "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem:
at Variable.main(Array.java:3)"

If I remove "public" infront of class Variable, it works. Why is that?

Comment: that makes no sense. the code as you posted it is valid java code. is there more code in your class?

Comment: What is the name of your Java file?

Comment: @Stultuske There is not any more code. I named my file the same as the class, in this case Variable.java

Comment: In that case, that code should compile just fine.

Comment: I was able to spot the mistake, VSC did not assign the class correctly, file needs to be safed as .java but plain txt type first. Thank you for your support nevertheless!

Comment: You say that it's Variable.java, but the error message indicates Array.java is the problem. Check whether you have an Array.java file...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The names of the class and the file in which it is located must match. A file can have only one class with the public modifier and any number of classes without modifiers. Probably the name of the class and the file do not match.

Comment: according to the OP, they do match

Comment: @Stultuske: The error message says otherwise.

Comment: Yes, small error in the detail as I saved it as java file but missed .java

Comment: "The names of the class and the file in which it is located must match" only one top-level class in a file can have the name of the file, and that class name is only required to match the filename if the class is public.

Answer (score 0):

The name of the java file must match the class name. When saving the file, save it using the class name and add ".java"

Comment: according to the OP, that's what he did.

Comment: Than it should definitely work because the code he wrote  which is 100% correct.

Comment: I guess, This is because Main thread is looking for main method() with predefined Variable class array argument. But here, it got main method() with user defined Variable class. Whenever Main thread will see a class name, it tries to search that class scope by scope. First it will see in your program, then in your package.If not found, then JVM follows delegation hierarchy principle to load that class.Hence you will get run-time error.
To run above program, we can also provide full path of Variable class.